# Is 他的自行车被我买了 grammatically wrong?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

> 他的自行车被我买了. (His bicycle was bought by me.)

As I learn, 被 structure tends to be used in negative conditions. In this sentence, I think it is not wrong but not smooth.

Can anyone explain if it is grammatically wrong and suggest me a better option?

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no wrong in your sentence.

You could also said like:

"我買了他的自行車" = "I bought his bicycle."

PS: 被 is not all negative, it should be "passive".(passively?)

Comment: 他的自行车被我买了 emphasize the object 他的自行车 (what happened to the bicycle? I bought it); 我買了他的自行車 doesn't emphasize anything

Comment: @TangHo yeah, I know what you mean, I have consider for a while, but "his bicycle" have means "他的", or if use "his own bicycle" will be better? Do you have any idea?

Comment: 他的 (his) refer to a third person's ; 我(I)  is the first person. "his own bicycle" means 他自己的, the sentence should be 他自己的自行车被我买了 which 自己 is redundant

Comment: @TangHo Thats why I did'nt add it in the sentence, but can't emphasize the object.

Comment: But this is another way to explain similar meaning.